# Need help to restrict route access to some id's

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, eloquent, routes

i need that guest's can access only to link 'fixtures/1' and 'fixtures/2'

when they manage to other id's, for exmpl 'fixtures/3' they should get something like "page not found"

i tryied like this:

```
Route::get('/fixtures/{team}', function ($team) {
    //
})->where($team, '1')->name('front.fixtures');
```

but it doesn't worked.
Can somebody help me, how i can add clause like this?

here is my route without any changes:

```
Route::get('/fixture/{team}', 'FrontController@fixtures')->name('front.fixtures');
```

**EDITED:**

I tryied to restrict with using if, but everytime i open page it doesn't check on id, here is my method:

```
public function fixtures(Request $request,Team $team = null) {
        $matches = Match::where('home_team_id', $team->id)
        ->orWhere('away_team_id', $team->id)
        ->paginate(20);
        $teams = Team::all();
        $team = $request->route()->parameter('team');

        if ($request->route('team') !== '1' || $request->route('team') !== '2') {
                return view('front.fixtures')->with([
                    'matches' => $matches,
                    'teams' => $teams,
                ]);
            } else {
                abort('404');
            }
    }
```

Comment: You should check middlewares in docs for this specific need. I'd go with middleware that checks which route is accessed and if accessed route is not `fixtures/1` nor `fixtures/1` then checks if user is authenticated. If not authenticated, `abort(404)` could be thrown otherwise request can be passed to the next pipe.

Comment: This is what policies are for. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

Answer (score 0):

Use this middleware code.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $auth = \Auth::check();
        if($auth == false){
            if ($request->route('team') == '3' || $request->route('team') == '5') {
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                abort('404');
            }

        } else{
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

Your route should be:

```
Route::get('/fixture/{team}', 'FrontController@fixtures')->middleware('name of 
                                                                    middleware');
```

Dont forget to register middleware in Karnel.php under protected $routeMiddleware.

[Read More about Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware)

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score -1):

What i usually do

in **app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Route::bind('institutionDocument', function ($id) {
            $this->CheckForSignedUser();
            $document = \App\Models\Document::find($di);

            return $document ?? abort(404);
        });
}
```

and in my route

```
Route::get(
    "documents/{institutionDocument}/preview",
    "DocumentsController@preview"
);
```